# Moto E on Lollipop has KitKat's boot animation

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot, motorola-moto-e

I have a Moto E 1st Gen. When I updated to Lollipop, my boot animation updated too, but a few months later I did a hard reset to my Moto E. All was great, but yesterday I noticed that my boot animation is back to what it was on KitKat.

Is there a problem, and what can I do?

Comment: No reason to downvote guys... It's a valid question

Comment: @RahulBasu, then consider fixing it please. I would definitely take my vote back if anybody makes it clear. It's a mess as of now.

Comment: @Firelord It could use a grammar edit, but the question is perfectly valid. I experienced the same thing. Put in a edit suggestion a min ago.

Comment: @EthanZ I didn't say the question is invalid. It's not written clearly (IMO) neither the question shows any efforts made by poster to attempt to solve the question. Please read [When should I vote down?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: How Sorry If I don't write correct, It's all because my 1st Language is not English, so I have some trouble with my spelling but I would take your advice the next time that I ask a Question

Answer (score 0):

My Moto X did this same thing for almost a month after Lollipop was released. Eventually, `Motorola Boot Services` updated through `Google Play` and the animation updated. It also introduced a few bugs Motorola has yet to fix, but give it time, and you will receive that update again relatively soon.

Comment: Actually I have the Update but isn't Available Play Store tell me that “Your device isn't compatible with this version”

Comment: @DanielBaker I don't know what to tell you then

Answer (score 0):

Motorola uses the Motorola boot services to provide custom boot animations that update frequently. As a result it stores the boot animation in the /data partition. Update boot services or clear data for it to bring back the lollipop boot animation.

The boot animation does not affect the device. You can continue using the device as is.

Comment: Actually I have the Update but isn't Available Play Store tell me that “Your device isn't compatible with this version”